# What does a conditional without a condition mean?

Tags: c, for-loop, conditional-statements

I am trying to read some C.  There is a for loop with a conditional that does not appear to be a condition.  In the for loop `for (h = n; h /= 2;)`, the conditional is `h/=2;`.  But this is not a true or false statement.  What does this mean?  When does this for loop end?

Here is the full code from http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Shell_sort#C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void shell_sort (int *a, int n) {
    int h, i, j, t;
    for (h = n; h /= 2;) {
        for (i = h; i < n; i++) {
            t = a[i];
            for (j = i; j >= h && t < a[j - h]; j -= h) {
                a[j] = a[j - h];
            }
            a[j] = t;
        }
    }
}

int main (int ac, char **av) {
    int a[] = {4, 65, 2, -31, 0, 99, 2, 83, 782, 1};
    int n = sizeof a / sizeof a[0];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d%s", a[i], i == n - 1 ? "\n" : " ");
    shell_sort(a, n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d%s", a[i], i == n - 1 ? "\n" : " ");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Imagine `!= 0` after the expression

Comment: C does not have a strong boolean data type.  There is `_Bool` in C99 and later, but even that's just an integer type.  In C, any integer expression that evaluates to zero represents false, and any other integer expression represents true.  Going the other way, relational expressions evaluate to integer values (0 or 1, as appropriate), and can be used as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will evaluate `h` after performing the augmented assignment operator `/=`, which divides `h` by the second operand and assigns the result back to `h`.
The condition will fail when `h` is 0.

A more readable equivalent would be

```
int h = n, i, j, t;
while (h /= 2) {
    ...
}
```

`for(h = n / 2; h; h /= 2) { ... }` is equivalent, too, but it's obviously messy repeating the increment in the initialisation just for the sake of having a for loop.

Answer (score 1):

The statement

```
h /= 2;
```

divides `h` by 2, assigns that new value to `h` and then evaluates that new value.  Hence, as soon as `h` becomes 0 due to repeated division by 2 (and it eventually will), the condition will become false and the loop will end.

Comment: So are you saying it is equivalent to:
for(h = n / 2; h != 0; h /= 2)?

Comment: Not exactly because `h` will have a different value inside the loop body but the iteration count would be the same.

Comment: @Evorlor Sorry, my bad.  Yes, it's exactly the same.

Comment: @Evorlor Sorry, misread your first comment. Yes, it is equivalent to that. Or `int h = n; while(h /= 2) {}` which IMO is clearer

Answer (score 0):

if something is 0, its false, if something is not 0, its true.

so h/= 2 will keep dividing h until it reaches 0, then quit the loop